# Tango With Django: User Authentication - User being saved but not receiving confirmation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am on chapter 9 of Tango With Django:

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/login.html#demo

Whenever I create a user, I get an error page on my browser as shown below:

```
    IntegrityError at /rango/register/
    rango_userprofile.user_id may not be NULL
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/register/
    Django Version: 1.7.1
    Exception Type: IntegrityError
    Exception Value:    
    rango_userprofile.user_id may not be NULL
    Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 485
    Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
    Python Version: 2.7.8
    Python Path:    
    ['C:\\Users\\Paul.Zovighian\\desktop\\tango\\tango_with_django_project',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-win32.egg',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2014.7-py2.7.egg',
     'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
     'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
     'C:\\Python27',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
    Server time:    Fri, 12 Dec 2014 16:50:14 +0000
```

I can see that there is an integrity error, but I am not sure why this is the message I get. If I try registering that user again, it won't let me because it says that that username already exists. So it's like, working for registering new users, but it just doesn't acknowledge the successful registration.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.slug = slugify(self.name)
                super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from rango.models import Category
from rango.models import Page
from rango.forms import CategoryForm
from rango.forms import PageForm
from rango.forms import UserForm, UserProfileForm

def index(request):
    # Query the database for a list of ALL categories currently stored.
    # Order the categories by no. likes in descending order.
    # Retrieve the top 5 only - or all if less than 5.
    # Place the list in our context_dict and dictionary which will be passed to the template engine.
    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
    page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]
    context_dict = {'categories': category_list, 'pages': page_list}

    # Render the response and send it back!
    return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)

def about(request):
    context_dict = {'italicmessage': "I am italicised font from the context"}
    return render(request, 'rango/about.html', context_dict)

def category(request, category_name_slug):

    # Create a context dictionary which we can pass to the template rendering engine
    context_dict = {}

    try:
        # Can we find a category name slug with the given name?
        # If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
        # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        context_dict['category_name'] = category.name

        # Retrieve all the associated pages.
        # Note that filter returns >= 1 model instance.
        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)

        # Adds our results list to the template context under name pages.
        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        # We also add the category object from the database to the context dictionary.
        # We'll use this in the template to verify that the category exists.
        context_dict['category'] = category
        context_dict['category_name_slug'] = category_name_slug

    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
        # Don't do anything - the template displayes the "no category message for us."
        pass

    # Go render the response and return it to the client.
    return render(request, 'rango/category.html', context_dict)

def add_category(request):
    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # save the new category to the database.
            form.save(commit=True)

            # Now call the index() view.
            # The user will be shown the homepage.
            return index(request)
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print form.errors
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = CategoryForm()

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render(request, 'rango/add_category.html', {'form': form})

def add_page(request, category_name_slug):

    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        cat = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit=False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                return category(request, category_name_slug)
    else:
        form = PageForm()

    context_dict = {'form': form, 'category': cat, 'category_name_slug': category_name_slug}

    return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)

def register(request):

    # A boolean value for telling the template whether the registration was successful.
    # Set to False initially. Code changes value to True when registration succeeds.
    registered = False

    # If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Attempt to grab information from the raw form information
        # Note that we make use of both UserForm and UserProfileForm.
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        # If the two forms are valid...
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to the database.
            user = user_form.save()

            # Now we hash the password with the set_password method.
            # Once hashed, we can update the user object.
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            # Now we sort out the UserProfile instance.
            # Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False
            # This delays saving the model until we're ready to avoid integrity problems.
            profile = profile_form.save()
            profile.user = user

            # Did the user provide a profile picture?
            # If so, we need to get it from the input form and put it in the UserProfile model.
            if  'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

            # Now we save the UserProfile model instance.
            profile.save()

            # Update our variables to tell the template registration was successful.
            registered = True

        # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
        # Print problems to the terminal.
        # They'll also be shown to the user.
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

    # Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two ModuleForm instances.
    # These forms will be blank, ready for user input.
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    # Render the template depending on the context.
    return render(request,'rango/register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered} )
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rango.models import Page, Category, UserProfile

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the category name.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the title of the page.")
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        exclude = ('category',)
                # or specify the fields to include (.i.e. not include the category field)
        #fields = ('title', 'url', 'views')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')

        # If url is not empty and doesn't start with 'http://', prepend 'http://'.
        if url and not url.startswith('http://'):
            url = 'http://' + url
            cleaned_data['url'] = url

        return cleaned_data

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('website', 'picture')
```

I think I have all relevant files included here, but let me know if I could provide any other info to clear things up!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment says "Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False", but you don't actually do that. It should be:

```
profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
```

In future, please cut your code down to the minimum that exhibits your problem: the error was occurring on register, you didn't need to show all the code relating to categories.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, and noted about trimming down the code, your help is appreciated!